# Can I have a vector attribute in WEKA?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, feature-engineering

I am new to WEKA/machine learning and I am trying to create a model in which a single feature is a vector of 8 integers (ranging from 0-11) containing information of past choices. For example, [0,1,8,4,4,2,2,6] would mean that 0 was chosen in the last iteration, 1 was chosen two iterations ago, etc. Each choice has an impact on the next in this case and the order is important.

I was wondering if it is possible to represent this in WEKA as a feature. I am currently representing them as individual features but this does not make the relation or order between the values obvious and I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weka's [ARFF format](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/arff_stable/) does not offer an attribute type that would allow you to encapsulate an ordered vector. Attributes are basically independent columns and the [relational attribute type](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/arff_stable/#relational-attributes) does not enforce an ordering either.

Your data sounds more like a time series. If that is the case, you could look a the [time series support in Weka](https://pentaho-community.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DATAMINING/pages/293700841/Time+Series+Analysis+and+Forecasting+with+Weka).

If your data does not represent a time series, then you may have to fall back on feature engineering. You can use the [AddExpression](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/AddExpression.html) filter for creating new attributes based on values from other attributes (e.g., difference between two attributes).

With the [MultiFilter](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/MultiFilter.html) you can combine an arbitrary number of filters into a single one. Which you then can use in conjunction with the [FilteredClassifier](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/FilteredClassifier.html) meta-classifier.